# Firebase Functions unable to download file from web

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have written the codes below to enable Firebase Functions to download a file from the web based on a URL path which I have specified. I didn't manage to get the code below to work as Firebase Function would fail with 503 error status with the message "Service Temporarily Unavailable". Is there a proper way to handle this?

```
function funcDownloadFile(urlToDownload, cb) {
  const sendReq = request.get(urlToDownload);
  // Verify response
  sendReq.on('response', function(response) {
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log("Error in download response.statusCode:"+ response.statusCode);
        console.log("Error in download response.statusMessage:"+ response.statusMessage);
          return cb('Response status was ' + response.statusCode);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more what the function needs to do and how you set it up in the firebase hosting? Do you call the function directly?

Comment: I need to download the file from a website and store it into the Firebase Storage. I am not using Firebase Hosting for this purpose. Yes, I call the function directly.

Comment: Do you get that error when your call your function? Or when your function tries to download that file? What payment plan does your firebase project have?

Comment: I have a Blaze plan. I have other functions that is working fine (other functions that is not related to downloading file from the web). The issue is when the file is download, it would report the error. There is no error prior to downloading a file from the web.

Comment: Can you share the full error log with use?